# TestNg's group-by-instances not working as expected

Tags: testng

I am using TestNg 6.8.8, and have been trying to get tests to execute per instance, with little luck. Could someone please help me understand where I am going wrong. The following is my code.

```
<suite name="ExtendFactory" order-by-instances="true">
    <test name="Factory"  order-by-instances="true" preserve-order="false">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.SampleTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

public class Sample {

    @DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public static Object[][] createData1() {
        return new Object[][] {
                { "Google" },
                { "Microsoft"},
        };
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test2")
    public static Object[][] createData2() {
        return new Object[][] {
                { "Apple"},
                { "Yahoo"},
        };
    }
}

public class SampleTest {
    @Test(dataProvider = "test1",dataProviderClass = Sample.class)
    public void verifyData1(String n1) {
        System.out.println(n1);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test2", dependsOnMethods="verifyData1",dataProviderClass = Sample.class)
    public void verifyData2(String n1) {
        System.out.println(n1);
    }
```

I want the result to be in this order : Google, Apple, Microsoft,Yahoo OR Apple,Yahoo,Google,Microsoft,
but I get Google,Microsoft,Apple,Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually not implemented factory in the mentioned situation. You have to create a class with @Factory annotation and then the factory class will call your test class. For all such cases group-by-instance is valid. For more reference follow testng documentation http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories

Comment: if use "Factory", the execution order is random not followed by dp